# HP HDX 16 Fails on WDS PXE BOOT

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, drivers, pxe

When I PXE boot my HP HDX 16 machine it will show the boot options. If I go Windows 7 x86 it will go to the screen to pick which Windows to install. However, if go with the Windows 8.1/Server 2012 R2 x64 boot options, I will eventually get this error:

```
wdsclient an error occurred while obtaining an ip address from the dhcp server...
```

Is this a driver issue or a possible 23/64 bit problem.

If this is a driver issue(so it sounds). How do I inject drivers in to the boot.wim and how do I know which drivers?

I currently reinstalled Windows 7 x64 with the boot image that booted (has 32/64 together).

I tried using DISM to inject the following 64bit drivers from http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3815320#N773

I still had the same timeout. The Windows 7 boot image get the DHCP but for some reason the Windows 8.1 boot does not even after driver injection.

I also downloaded the Windows 8 and Server 2012 from http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false but I still get the same problems. DHCP does not seem to respond. The BIOS shows RTL8111B/RTL8111C as the NIC.

I did notice that on bootup the NIC took 10 or so seconds to get an IP/kick into DHCP getting an IP. Could this be an issue as mentioned at the bottom of this article?
http://blogs.technet.com/b/svengruenitz/archive/2008/06/30/wds-client-dhcp-issues-here-is-one-solution.aspx

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the driver does not correspond to the 64-bit systems and 32-bit systems, windows8 next update drivers have done, you can look HP HDX.
http://binarydb.com/driver/HP-HDX-Elite-Mouse-112834.html